# An example of a man asked for a sign, been given the sign, then rejecting the sign, but he repents afterwards?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, midrash

I wonder if there is a case in The Torah, of a man (or group of people) asking God for a miracle, then God offered the miracle, but the man rejected the sign, or accepted the sign but later will show disrespect to God, not following his words and not behaving justly.but ultimately this same man repents getting back to God ?

any case typical of such behaviour?

thanx for help